# Missing END - Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am very used to writing in TSQL and MySQL is taking some adjusting but I think I am getting most of it. I have one stored procedure however that will not budge, I have read and re-read it 100 times, read up all I can find on the error and still no luck.

On Line 11 and the end of this statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ReturnAvalRooms (roomID int);
```

I get the error "Missing End" even though this is at the beginning of my query.
I have checked and double checked that everything is Declared and Set with appropriate ; but just can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Below is a full copy of the Stored Procedure.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_AvailRooms` (IN StartDate datetime, IN EndDate datetime, IN RoomType int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE PStartDate datetime;
    DECLARE PEndDate datetime;
    DECLARE PRoomType int;
    SET PStartDate = StartDate;
    SET PEndDate = EndDate;
    SET PRoomType = RoomType;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AvaliableNowRooms AS (SELECT idRooms FROM rooms WHERE RoomNextAvail < PStartDate AND RoomTypeID = PRoomType);
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ReturnAvalRooms (roomID int); 

    DECLARE AvailRooms CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM AvaliableNowRooms;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    DECLARE RoomID INT;

    OPEN AvailRooms;

    read_loop: LOOP

    FETCH AvailRooms INTO RoomID;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

            DECLARE Bookings CURSOR FOR SELECT BookingStartDate, BookingEndDate, BookingRoomID FROM Booking WHERE BookingRoomID = RoomID AND BookingEndDate < PStartDate;
            DECLARE PBookingStartDate datetime;
            DECLARE PBookingEndDate datetime;
            DECLARE PBookingRoomID,

            OPEN Bookings

            Booking_Read: LOOP
            FETCH Bookings INTO PBookingStartDate, PBookingEndDate, PBookingRoomID;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            END IF;

            IF PBookingStartDate BETWEEN PStartDate AND PEndDate
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            ELSE IF PBookingEndDate BETWEEN PStartDate AND PEndDate
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO ReturnAvalRooms (id) values (PBookingRoomid);
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE Bookings;
            END

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE AvailRooms;
    END

    SELECT * FROM ReturnAvalRooms

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is particular about the order of the DECLARE statements. Within a block, those have to appear first.  And (I believe) the HANDLERs have to be the last declarations.

I'm confused by what your procedure is intending to return. It seems like you'd want to return all rooms of the specified type for which there isn't any booking that overlaps the specified period.

But looking at the logic in the procedure, it seems like if there are no rows in booking for a given room, that room won't be returned.  And that seems odd.  And that has me puzzled about what this is really supposed to return. The specification is obfuscated by a lot of unnecessary clutter.

The whole rigmarole could be accomplished by a single SQL statement which is much simpler, much clearer, and more efficient to boot.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_AvailRooms` (IN PStartDate datetime, IN PEndDate datetime, IN PRoomType int)
BEGIN
-- rooms of the specified type which are "available" for the 
-- specified period.  A room is considered not available if 
-- the RoomNextAvail col has a date value later than the beginning
-- of the specified period, or there are one or more bookings that
-- overlap that period. If the specified StartDate is later than
-- the specified EndDate, then no rooms are available.
-- 
-- This query uses an "anti-join" pattern to return only rows 
-- in rooms which don't have a overlapping booking

   SELECT r.idRooms
     FROM rooms r
     LEFT
     JOIN Booking b
       ON b.BookingRoomID = r.idRooms
      AND b.BookingEndDate    >= PStartDate
      AND b.BookingStartDate  <= PEndDate
    WHERE b.idRooms IS NULL
      AND r.RoomTypeID        = PRoomType
      AND r.RoomNextAvail     < PStartDate
      AND          PStartDate < PEndDate
    ORDER BY r.idRooms;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

That's just a first cut; it's not tested. We might want to change the `<=` and `>=` to be just `<` and `>`, depending on whether or not we consider a booking that ends at exactly 10AM overlaps with a period starting right at 10AM.

Comment: +10 For style - Have given this query a few goes now with a few alterations to account for newly created rooms having a null avail date and so far I can't fault it. The original theory if you want to know was the first temp table would capture all available rooms regardless of future bookings. Once that happened, it could loop through the bookings table with that roomID and collect all future bookings, checking for date cross over then adding it to a temp table if there was none. Yours is much nicer. Thank you! The testing continues...

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables at the top of the procedure. Also you are not using `THEN` after `IF` statement. Correct the code. Also, you are closing the `loop` before closing the `IF` block.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_AvailRooms` (IN StartDate datetime, IN EndDate datetime, IN RoomType int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE PStartDate datetime;
    DECLARE PEndDate datetime;
    DECLARE PRoomType int;
    DECLARE AvailRooms CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM AvaliableNowRooms;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    DECLARE RoomID INT;
    DECLARE Bookings CURSOR FOR SELECT BookingStartDate, BookingEndDate,   BookingRoomID FROM Booking WHERE BookingRoomID = RoomID AND BookingEndDate < PStartDate;
    DECLARE PBookingStartDate datetime;
    DECLARE PBookingEndDate datetime;
    DECLARE PBookingRoomID,
    SET PStartDate = StartDate;
    SET PEndDate = EndDate;
    SET PRoomType = RoomType;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AvaliableNowRooms AS (SELECT idRooms FROM rooms WHERE RoomNextAvail < PStartDate AND RoomTypeID = PRoomType);
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ReturnAvalRooms (roomID int); 

    OPEN AvailRooms;

    read_loop: LOOP

    FETCH AvailRooms INTO RoomID;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

            OPEN Bookings

            Booking_Read: LOOP
            FETCH Bookings INTO PBookingStartDate, PBookingEndDate, PBookingRoomID;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            END IF;

            IF PBookingStartDate BETWEEN PStartDate AND PEndDate THEN
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            ELSE IF PBookingEndDate BETWEEN PStartDate AND PEndDate THEN
                LEAVE Booking_Read;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO ReturnAvalRooms (id) values (PBookingRoomid);
            END;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE Bookings;
            END

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE AvailRooms;
    END

    SELECT * FROM ReturnAvalRooms

END
```

Comment: I wish I could mark two as right, you answer is correct and fixed the originally posed issue, though spencer presented a much nicer solution.

Comment: " but just can't figure out why I am getting this error.". I just made your proc error free. Atleast you can upvote if you found the answer correct.